# Сравнить две строки без учета регистра в JS

Tags: javascript, строки

Есть необходимость сравнить две строки без учета регистра. Например, есть две строки `"ivanovii"` и `"IvanovII"`, формально это одно и тоже. Также может быть и так: `"Ivanovii"` и `"IvanovII"`. Вообщем нужно как то сравнить строки не учитывая регистр, как это можно сделать?

Comment: привести их к одному регистру и затем сравнить

Comment: @Grundy, черт, я одновременно ответ написал)

Comment: Например, использовать для каждой из строк [`str.ToUpperCase`](http://javascript.ru/string/touppercase) а потом сравнивать между собой.

Comment: @Утка, ты не одинок с этим )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Приведите их к одному регистру.
У строк есть методы [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase), [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase);

```
var myStr = 'приветики',
    mySecondStr = 'ПрИвЕтИкИ';

console.log(myStr.toUpperCase() === mySecondStr.toUpperCase());
```